# Have a particle system's particles obey transparency sort mode individually

Tags: unity, particles

### Background

In a top-down game, I have particles that spawn animated textures. I have my 2D renderer settings set-up so that it orders sprites based on their position on th Y-axis via "Transparency Sort Mode > Custom Axis > Y".

### The Problem

But instead of sorting for each particle spawned, what happens is the particle system obeys the setting as a whole so that the sort order is only based on the particle's system's center.

Is there a way to have each particle obey Transparency Sort Mode individually?

What I want for each particle:

[image: Green spikes go behind gray fence based on their individual pivot.]

What actually happens:

[image: Green spikes go behind gray fence based on the center of the particle system.]

### Other Solutions

Other people seem to have an old workaround to use GetParticles and setting their "order in layer" individually. See this thread from 2015:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/particle-systems-with-sprites-order-in-layer.464533/

But I'm trying to find if there's a cleaner solution for Unity 2019 without having to fudge with "order in layer".

Comment: did you found any good solution for this?

Comment: @deepankar So far, no.